# Nginx as reverse proxy for Ajenti

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have setup a server block for `Ajenti` as per -> http://support.ajenti.org/topic/349870-ajenti-behind-nginx/

```
location /ajenti {
    rewrite (/ajenti)$ / break;
    rewrite /ajenti/(.*) /$1 break;

    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_redirect /        /ajenti/;
    proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection $http_connection;
}
```

Which gets me to the login, but after I login `Ajenti` redirects to "/ajenti:auth" and not "/ajenti/ajenti:auth".

E.g.: Browser -> HTTPS -> Nginx -> HTTP -> Ajenti

It also seems to be an issue for "ajenti:static" resources too.

See: http://support.ajenti.org/topic/88086-support-ajenti-behind-a-reverse-proxy/

What is the recommended way to handle this in `Nginx`?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Adding `proxy_set_header Origin http://$host;` fixes it for me.

After upgrading to the latest version of ajenti I also have this problem as well. Error 403 Invalid Origin. This is my setup.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ajenti.mymagicalwebsite.com;
    ssl on;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header        Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection      "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout      36000s;  ## Timeout after 10 hours
    }
}
```

Funny that it all worked a version ago with this exact same setup.

Comment: Adding this line did the trick, I'm guessing since I am doing my proxy from HTTPS to HTTP.
`proxy_set_header Origin http://$host;`

Comment: - as per your comment (Hardex) above, but http -> "proxy_set_header Origin http://$host;"

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

Use `location ~ /ajenti.*` instead to match Ajenti's resources URLs.

**Edit**: tested that and it works.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work for me. I added the .* to the end of the location and I get a 404.

Just noticed (in the browser console) that the POST (after I login) is returning "403 invalid origin"?

Comment: Did you specify the regex location matching? E.g. `location ~ /ajenti.*`

Comment: I should have put it in the answer, sorry